# How can I save all of the images in a Word 2007 document as separate files?

Tags: word-2007, inline-images

How can I save all of the images/figures in a Word 2007 document as separate files?  Right now I have to save each one separately.  And I can't even save them from within Word -- I have to copy them to PowerPoint and then save them since there doesn't seem to be any way to save them from within Word.

[Note that the trick shown at TechRepublic (http://blogs.techrepublic.com.com/itdojo/?p=135) does not work.  It doesn't work because all of my images are cropped and this trick produces uncropped images.

Similarly, saving as an HTML file doesn't work because the image files linked to in the HTML document are uncropped.]

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just save the entire document as a full html file? Then open up the folders it creates, they should be saved in there somewhere because they have to be linked into the html.

Comment: This doesn't work for the same reason that the TR trick doesn't work: The separate files are uncropped.